# How to find which controller I'm passing to another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have two table view controllers `StudentsTableViewController` and `TeachersTableViewController` which displays students name and teachers name respectively, and I have only one `DetailTableViewController` which displays Details of them in sections. I have different sections for these two controllers. 
 
 I'm using storyBoard ID for pushing. Now my question is , how to find which controller I'm passing to `DeatilViewController`

Comment: Take 2 arrays for Teachers & Students. According to click u have to send a value , according that value you can show the data on TableView.

Comment: When you are on detailviewcontroller you would like to find out which controller(student or teacher) you came from?

Comment: Thanks @SRNayak.. Why do we need arrays for just knowing which controller im passing ??

Comment: @SRNayak yes exactly..

Comment: @Daya Kevin:Its Working or not?

Comment: Array for keeping data & take a Variable for checking just knowing which controller u came from

Comment: @SRNayak yes working.. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

In your **DetailViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL comeFromStudentsTable;
```

In your **StudentsTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueID_toStudentTable"])
   {
       DeatilViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
       vc.comeFromStudentsTable=YES;

   }
}
```

In your **TeachersTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueID_toTeacherTable"])
   {
       DeatilViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
       vc.comeFromStudentsTable=NO;

   }
}
```

In your **DetailViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   if (self.comeFromStudentsTable)
   {
        // do what you want If come from student 
   }
   else
   {
       // do what you want If come from teacher 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify it using the kind of class object being passed to the DetailViewController.

For example: Make property of the detail object in DetailViewController

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) id detailObject; //This will be object of Student/Teacher class.
```

Now in DetailViewController you can make condition like this:

```
if([self.detailObject isKindOfClass:[Teacher class]])
    {
        //Do code for Teacher details
    }
    else{
        //Do code for Student details
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your detail VC write this to get the VC that pushed you.

`NSArray* navStack = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController* parent = navStack[MIN((NSInteger)navStack.count - 2, 0)];
/* -2, -1 because count isn't a valid index, and -1 for the current VC */`

That being said this is very brittle, and you are better off adopting a common protocol between the two VCs or have a reflection check (i.e. `isKindOfClass:...`) based on the object you're trying to show (and thus not care about how you got about the semantics of *how* you got here rather *what* object got you here).

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(UIViewController *childVC in [self.navigationController viewControllers]){
If([childVC isKindOfClass: [StudentViewController class])
{
//StudentViewController object you can get //from self.navigationalController
    }

else If([childVC isKindOfClass: [TeacherViewController class])
{
//TeacherViewController object you can get //from self.navigationalController
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't compiled the code I just typed on my mobile it should work

Answer (score -2):

Thanks guys. I came with another logic using storyBoard ID.. 
In "**StudentTableViewController.m**"

```
DetailTableViewController *detailController;
detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailTVC"];
NSString *identifier = @"StudentTableViewController";
detailController.controllerIdentifier = identifier; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

In "**TeacherTableViewController.m**"

```
DetailTableViewController *detailController;
detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailTVC"];
NSString *identifier = @"TeacherTableViewController";
detailController.controllerIdentifier = identifier;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

In "**DetailTableViewController.h**"

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *controllerIdentifier;
```

In "**DetailTableViewController.m**"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { <br>
    NSLog(@"Passed controller is %@",controllerIdentifier); 
}
```